# tsdiscon after startup

Tags: windows-xp, session

I have a test server running on Windows XP SP3.

I need to do the following:

1. Boot
2. Automatically login WWW user
3. Start a WWW server (I'm using IIS Express)
4. Disconnect (not logout) the WWW user (maybe using the tsdiscon command)

This will allow to keep a test site always online while other user (in turn) may connect to the machine using different usernames through Remote Desktop.

I have setup 3 bat scripts:

**Script A** (located at Startup folder):

```
@echo off
start "IIS Express" /min cmd.exe /k "C:\Documents and  Settings\WWW\My Documents\IISExpress\scripts\StartIisExpress.bat"
start "Disconnect User" /min cmd.exe /k "C:\Documents and Settings\WWW\My Documents\IISExpress\scripts\DisconnectUser.bat"
```

**Script B**:

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /config:"C:\Documents and Settings\WWW\My Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config" > NUL
```

**Script C**:

```
tsdiscon
```

Every thing works as expected until it reaches the **tsdiscon** script. I returns an error message:

`Could not get the current sessionname, Error code 1702.
The binding handle is invalid.`

Obviously the WWW user doesn't get disconnects but if I type **tsdiscon** and press Enter manually it will work as expected.

Any hints on this? I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own problem.

The way to go, cleaner and lighter, is to setup a Scheduled Task for start IIS Express script (B).

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether you get the script working or not, Windows XP allows for only one user session at a time so there's no way (that I know of) to have a disconnected user session and allow another user session at the same time.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but Win XP supports Fast User Switching which allows for a user to disconnect leaving its processes running. There can be many users logged but only one ACTIVE user.